Android: How to configure stable resource id's with aapt2
In my android app I use custom notification sounds from the raw folder for my notification channels. The sounds are passed to the notification channels as URI with Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.resourceId). Works everything as expected, as long as no additional files are added to the raw folder. If this is the case, the resource id can change and therefore the URI of the notification channel points to the wrong resource.
I was searching for a solution to have stable resource id's. So e.g. if I add or remove a file from the raw folder the id for a resource stays the same.
In the aapt2 doc https://developer.android.com/tools/aapt2#link it's written, that during the link phase this can be achieved by using the --emit-ids together with the --stable-ids flag. Unfortunately I couldn't find any example how this is correctly configured in gradle.
So the most obvious solution was, to add the appt config to my gradle file as follows:
android {
   aaptOptions {
      additionalParameters "--emit-ids", buildDir.path, "--stable-ids", buildDir.path + "/stable-ids.txt"
   }
}

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to get it to work. The path argument of --emit-ids seems to be ignored at all. I can use any path, the file is always created with path build/intermediates/stable_resource_ids_file/debug/processDebugResources/stableIds.txt.
And consuming the created file with --stable-ids always leads to the error AAPT: ... error: failed reading stable ID file.. Even if I use the exact path to processDebugResources folder.
My goal is, to have stable resource id's for every release build. I don't know if this is even possible with the aapt2 build tool or if I have to use another approach.

I'm a bit confused. As known, resource IDs are assigned by aapt2, i.e. during compile-time. Now -- When do you add or remove the files in the /raw directory? In run-time or before compile-time? If before compile-time, no problems should occur unless you hardcode IDs which would be a really bad idea. If in run-time, then this would be a faulty approach per se.

@Krokomot The files are added before compile-time. The problem is following: E.g. a file named "file_b" is added to the /raw folder, a notification channel is created with R.raw.file_b as sound. So the notification channel sound points to e.g. resource id 0x7f0d0000. Afterwards the app is released, everything fine. Now if another file called "file_a" is added to the /raw folder, the new file gets the resource id 0x7f0d0000 and the old one the id 0x7f0d0001 (as it's ordered alphabetically). It the new release, the notification sound points to the wrong resource.

At the moment the workaround is, to recreate all notification channels with a new id, if files were added or deleted in /raw folder.
Unfortunately, Android creates a notification channel that already existed once with the same ID, with exactly the same settings (also the same sound resource id) as when it was first initialized. From my point of view, this is very unpleasant.
